# Or and And condition in same IF statement behaves differently

Tags: c#, .net

Please find my sample program below,

Condition 3 should not be true as per my inputs. But it returns true and statement inside if is getting executed. Help me to have better understanding of this.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string temp = null;
        string temp1 = "0";
        string temp2 = "1";
        if (temp1 == "0" || temp2 == "2" && temp == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Contion 1 satisfied");
        }
        if (temp1 == "0" || temp2 == "1" && temp == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Contion 2 satisfied");
        }
        if (temp1 == "0" || temp2 == "1" && temp != null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Contion 3 satisfied");
        }
        if (temp1 == "1" || temp2 == "1" && temp != null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Contion 4 satisfied");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: && operator has higher priority than || operator

Comment: A tip: When I combine boolean operators (ANDs and ORs) I don't want to remember which goes first, I *always* use brackets.

Comment: @IVAAAN123: but `temp` is null.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so what? true || false => true

Comment: brackets are your friend `temp1 || (temp2 && temp)`, Aside from producing the correct result, it also introduces clarity when reading your code

Comment: The first || separates two conditions: 1) `temp1 == "0"` 2) `temp2 == "1" && temp != null`. Since the first is already true, the second doesn't need to be evaluated.

Comment: @TimSchmelter at first calculated temp2 == "1" && temp != null, because && has higher priority

Comment: @IVAAAN123: no, `true || false` --> `true`

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are right, because of this he receives true at condition 3

Comment: @IVAAAN123: no, from left to right, since `temp1 == "0"` is already true the second condition doesn't need to be evaluated. And yes, if it has to be evaluated the `&&` had a higher precedence.

Comment: @TimSchmelter just see answers, maybe they give explanation for you..

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The only reason the short circuiting works as you've described is because `&&` has a higher priority. Your comment where you separate the two conditions is only valid because `&&` has higher precedence and thus is grouped together as a single statement. Compare to `false && true || true`. Here by your left to right logic that would evaluate to false due to short circuiting. In fact though it splits it as `(false && true) || true`. You are right that the short circuiting means it doesn't have to bother evaluating the `&&` but that isn't why the result is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was too hasty, yet again. The issue has to do with both operator [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) and [short-circuit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) evaluation of the logical condition:

- because of the precedence, the statement is evaluated as follows:

  ```
  (x || (y && z)) ~ (temp1 == "0" || (temp2 == "1" && temp != null))
  ```
- and here the short-circuit evaluation kicks in - because left side of the `||` operator is already `true` e.g. `temp1 == "0"` the right part is simply skipped.

  > The operation
  >
  > `x || y`
  >
  > corresponds to the operation
  >
  > `x | y`
  >
  > **except that if x is true, y is not evaluated because the OR operation is true regardless of the value of y**. This concept is known as "short-circuit" evaluation.

Comment: But the exlplanation is misleading The precendece of `&&` has nothing to do with the reason why it is `true`. That is (imho) what OP is asking, why does `&&` not work as expected? The reason is that it gets evaluated from left to right and the first condition (left side of `||`) is already true -> no need to evaluate the right side. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

Comment: You could even write this condition without getting an `DivideByZeroException`: `int zero = 0; if (temp1 == "0" || 100 / zero == 0 && 100 / zero == 0)`. So the `&&` does not matter at all in this question.

Comment: Remember that short-circuit is an optimization.  As long as there are no side-effects, it will not change the outcome.  So you can turn it off and the outcome will be the same.

Comment: Surely precendence is most important. The fact that `&&` is of higher precedene is exactly why the short circuiting works as you've described. ie `x || y && z` is equivalent to `x || (y && z)` because `&&` has higher precedence. If `||` had higher precedence it would be equivalent to `(x || y) && z` which would be false in case 4 exactly as the OP expected. The fact that it doesn't actually bother to evaluate the `(y&&z)` part is totally irrelevant in this questions since it only makes a practical difference if there are side effects.

Comment: I deleted the comment I had here just now. Precendence is totally the reason for this to work. short circuit is why it won't bother to evaluate the `&&` part but precedence is why it can group that part together as a single operand for the || operator.

Comment: Thanks for the new edit, @Yuriy. Now got my +1.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking why `true || true && false` is true.  It could be interpreted in two ways:

Left-to right: `(true || true) && false` --> should be false, which is what you are expecting.

But due to && having higher precedence, it is being interpreted like this: `true || (true && false)`.  The part in parenthesis is false, so that simplifies to `true || false`.

It is equivalent to why humans read `5 + 3 * 8` as `5 + (3 * 8)` and not `(5 + 3) * 8`.

Others mentioned short-circuit evaluation.  Short-circuit is an optimization technique, and will not change the actual answer as long as what you're evaluating has no side effects.  So if short-circuit evaluation was turned off, the outcome would be the same.

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation matters if the right side could have side effects like throwing an exception if the left side was already true(`int zero = 0; if (true || 100 / zero == 0 && 100 / zero == 0)` works). It matters also because the precedence of the operators does not need to be taken into account by the compiler since the short-circuit evaluation and the left-to-right order of evaluation will prevent  the right side(including `&&`) from being evaluated. Conclusion: the compiler does not care about operator precedence in this case.

Comment: Left-to-right evaluation is this: `(true || true) && false`.  This does not prevent the right side from evaluating, just the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), operator `&&` has greater priority, so:

1. `temp2 == "1" && temp != null` evaluates `false`. Remarks: in this case, this condition would never be evaluted due to lazy evaluation (the condition `temp1 == "1"` is true, so the second operator don't have to be checked - result is already known).
2. `temp1 == "0" || false` evaluates `true` (due to first condition).

Comment: Here also, the operator precedence is not the answer to this question but the order of evaluation (from left to right). The `&&` doesn't matter because `temp == "1"` is already true.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know, it is included in point 1.

Comment: well, the precedence of `&&` does not matter at all here but it's still the core topic of your answer. Actually nothing behind the first `||` gets evalauted  because `temp2 == "1"` is definitely true.

Comment: @TimSchmelter why? consider: `true || true && false`. If OP doesn't know the precedense, he could evalute the condition: `true || true && false` =>  `true && false` => `false` (what is wrong due to precednce). So I think that the precednce still has matter.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't matter what is on the right side of `||` if the left side is definitely true. Imho OP has also taken the wrong way because he wondered why the `true && false` didn't yield `false`.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't matter what is on the right side of `||` but still: he could evalute also the condition like in my comment above - where precedence has matter.